# Rewrite source with iptables

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn

I'm going to route a static IP from a VPS to my OpenWRT router. They are connected with OpenVPN - the server is the 10.8.0.1 and the router the 10.8.0.6. My public IP is 1.1.1.1 for example, and all traffic should go to the 10.8.0.6 - but my router has to send the answer to the server, because the default route of my OpenWRT is my adsl modem. So I just want to route traffic, which comes orginally to 1.1.1.1 and the answer to these packages over my VPN.

I've tried several firewall configurations, mainly this: [Does NAT-ing rewrite the source IP in packets?](https://serverfault.com/questions/530886/does-nat-ing-rewrite-the-source-ip-in-packets) - but it isn't working. With tcpdump on my home router the original sender IP is visible. All traffic goes first to the VPS, which has two IPs. It's a KVM box and I have full root access and even can use iptables. First, I route all traffic to the 1.1.1.1 to my home router over the vpn:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.1/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.6
```

This is working so far; pings to the 1.1.1.1 from another server are arriving on tun0 at my home router. But the problem is, that the ICMP reply leaves my router over eth0 and so over my ADSL modem, because the sender of the ping (84.200.34.2XX) fits no route, so the default route is taken. What can I do, that the source of any packages to 10.8.0.6 will be rewritten to the servers IP, 10.8.0.1, and the server will send every package to the original source?

tl;dr:

- Traffic comes from 84.200.34.2XX, goes to 1.1.1.1
- my VPS forwards package to my router in an OpenVPN (10.8.0.6)
- my router answers to the original source IP (84.200.34.2XX), but over his default route over an ADSL modem, which has a pretty different external IP

So, I want to have all incoming traffic on my home router not from the original source IP, but from the OpenVPN server (10.8.0.1), because OpenWRT has a route for it and can route answers to these packages over VPN. My VPS has to edit the anwer packages again, so that the source IP is 1.1.1.1. I cannot route all my private traffic over the VPN, because I have a traffic limitation on the VPS.

Has anyone a solution for a problem like this? I'm trying the whole evening (since 4 hours), but not successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, the following did it for me:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.1/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.6
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
```